# android animation switching UI and the active class

Tags: android, xml

so im traying to use the slid animation from android sampels 2,0,1 but when i but when im Switching the UI i also wan't to start using a new class / java file insted off using the same this is what i have trayed

```
ViewFlipper vf = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.details);

     // Set an animation from res/anim: I pick push left in
     vf.setAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(view.getContext(), R.anim.push_left_in));

     vf.showNext();

            startActivity(i);
```

but it is creashing with a null point exeception

01-06 00:20:21.373: E/AndroidRuntime(2982): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-06 00:20:21.373: E/AndroidRuntime(2982): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{simon.vestergaard.note.calender/simon.vestergaard.note.calender.NoteSelector}: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-06 00:20:21.373: E/AndroidRuntime(2982):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1955)
01-06 00:20:21.373: E/AndroidRuntime(2982):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1980)
01-06 00:20:21.373: E/AndroidRuntime(2982):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:122)
01-06 00:20:21.373: E/AndroidRuntime(2982):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1146)
01-06 00:20:21.373: E/AndroidRuntime(2982):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-06 00:20:21.373: E/AndroidRuntime(2982):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-06 00:20:21.373: E/AndroidRuntime(2982):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
01-06 00:20:21.373: E/AndroidRuntime(2982):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-06 00:20:21.373: E/AndroidRuntime(2982):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-06 00:20:21.373: E/AndroidRuntime(2982):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
01-06 00:20:21.373: E/AndroidRuntime(2982):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
01-06 00:20:21.373: E/AndroidRuntime(2982):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-06 00:20:21.373: E/AndroidRuntime(2982): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-06 00:20:21.373: E/AndroidRuntime(2982):     at simon.vestergaard.note.calender.NoteSelector.initilize(NoteSelector.java:65)
01-06 00:20:21.373: E/AndroidRuntime(2982):     at simon.vestergaard.note.calender.NoteSelector.onCreate(NoteSelector.java:53)
01-06 00:20:21.373: E/AndroidRuntime(2982):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
01-06 00:20:21.373: E/AndroidRuntime(2982):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
01-06 00:20:21.373: E/AndroidRuntime(2982):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1919)
01-06 00:20:21.373: E/AndroidRuntime(2982):     ... 11 more

this is my oncreate

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //      setContentView(R.layout.noteselectorscreen);

            initilize();
    }

    private void initilize() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Bback =(Button)findViewById(R.id.Bback);
            Bnew =(Button)findViewById(R.id.Bnew);
            LMain =(ListView) findViewById(R.id.LnoteSelector);
            tCatagoryName=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.TcatagoryName);
            TVtopText =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.TVtopText);


            Bback.setOnClickListener(this);
            Bnew.setOnClickListener(this);
            LMain.setOnItemClickListener(this);

            aa = new FancyAdapter();
            LMain.setAdapter(aa);
            FillListDataWithData();
            String caragorynameHeader =mainClass.getSelectedCategory();
            tCatagoryName.setText(""+caragorynameHeader);
            TVtopText.setText(R.string.app_name);

    }
```

the app is creahing one line 65 with is Bback.setOnClickListener(this);
how can i make this work?? so i'm also chaning the active class / the one in use ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you want to animate between 2 different Activities then you shouldn't be using a ViewFlipper. A ViewFlipper is used for 2 different views within the same Activity.

You should use

```
startActivity(intent);
overridePendingTransition(int enterAnim, int exitAnim);
```

this will animate from the first Activity to the second, if you wish animate back to the first Activity from the second then you need to override the back button in the second Activity.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed(){
    finish();
    overridePendingTransition(int enterAnim, int exitAnim);
}
```

As for the null pointer, the code you've posted shows

```
//      setContentView(R.layout.noteselectorscreen);
```

you need to uncomment this line, without calling `setContentView(layoutID)`, using  `findViewById(layoutID)` will return null, which is why `Bback` is null.

Comment: lol just found that code like 2 minutes ago but ty for the answere